# Capitalize question after colon or not?

Tags: capitalization, colons

I am wondering whether I should capitalize the first word after the colon in the following sentence:

> I wondered: **h**ow can I utilize knowledge of algebra to reach my goals?

All resources on the internet I found dealt with different cases, such as enumerating after a colon. However, I am almost putting a different sentence after the colon.

I am aware I could rephrase the sentence not to include a colon, but I need to include it.

Comment: The Oxford Manual of Style says that it is only necessary when introducing direct or paraphrased speech, or quoted material.

Comment: You can capitalize, or not, a sentence after a colon: it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definitely not: when do you capitalise? When you end a sentence.**

In my mind, this is simple: you have not ended a sentence, so you do not need to capitalise the initial letter.

On the other hand, if you are quoting (even if you are quoting yourself), it is optional.

> I wondered: "**H**ow can I utilise knowledge of algebra to reach my goals?".

Note the full stop after the quotation; if you have capitalised the initial letter, then you are treating it as a separate *sub-sentence*, as such, you end the sub-sentence and then you end the super-sentence, much like algebraic brackets.

Comment: Another case where it is common to capitalise after a colon is in titles, as in [all these many examples](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/titles-containing-colons) where the initial word after the colon is frequently of a type (article, preposition) that would not have been capitalised if it hadn’t been preceded by a colon.